# Trying to make a simple echo client server program work between two computers

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, client-server

I have been trying to resolve this issue but with no success so finally i am here to get some help from experts.

I just wanted to make a simple client server program work between two computers.

The server will reside in my laptop which is connected to the internet through a linksys router.

The client will reside in a university computer. I scped the file to a university computer and then i run it through ssh.

Now also two things worth noting is that i have also disabled firewall in my computer as well as i have configured port forwaring in my linksys router i.e it will forward request to the port to my ipaddress. I have also made my ipadddress static.

Here is the server code to reside in my laptop.

```
/* EchoServer.java
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2000 Sean Walton and Macmillan Publishers.  Use may be in
 * whole or in part in accordance to the General Public License (GPL).
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE REGENTS AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
 * ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE REGENTS OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
 * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
 * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS
 * OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
 * HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
 * LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY
 * OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
 * SUCH DAMAGE.
*/

/*****************************************************************************/
/*** EchoServer.java                                                       ***/
/***                                                                       ***/
/*****************************************************************************/

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EchoServer
{
    public EchoServer(int portnum)
    {
        try
        {
            server = new ServerSocket(portnum);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            System.out.println(err);
        }
    }

    public void serve()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {

                Socket client = server.accept();

                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                w.println("Welcome to the Java EchoServer.  Type 'bye' to close.");
                String line;
                do
                {
                    line = r.readLine();
                    if ( line != null )
                        w.println("Got: "+ line);
                }
                while ( !line.trim().equals("bye") );
                client.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            System.err.println(err);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EchoServer s = new EchoServer(3000);
        s.serve();
    }

    private ServerSocket server;
}
```

Here is the client code that will reside in university computer.

```
/* EchoClient.java
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2000 Sean Walton and Macmillan Publishers.  Use may be in
 * whole or in part in accordance to the General Public License (GPL).
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE REGENTS AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
 * ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE REGENTS OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
 * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
 * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS
 * OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
 * HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
 * LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY
 * OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
 * SUCH DAMAGE.
*/

/*****************************************************************************/
/*** EchoClient.java                                                       ***/
/***                                                                       ***/
/*****************************************************************************/

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EchoClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket s = new Socket("my static ip address here", 3000);
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader con = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line;
            do
            {
                line = r.readLine();
                if ( line != null )
                    System.out.println(line);
                line = con.readLine();
                w.println(line);
            }
            while ( !line.trim().equals("bye") );
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            System.err.println(err);
        }
    }
}
```

When i run it(both). The client program runs and it halts without any error. It just hangs.

I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: Does it hang as in not respond or hang as in nothing happens? You requested it retrieve a new line from stdin, which means it should block until input is available. Try type something in your console and press enter. And btw when `line == null` that normally means the stream is closed (and you should break out of that while loop)

Comment: it works fine in the same machine but not in different..by hang, i meant nothing happens even if you type something and enter..i think it is just blocking and waiting for a reply and after a while i get connection timed out java exception

Comment: also i wanted to add that when i do ping from university computer to my ipaddress it hangs indefinately..what does that suggest?

Comment: Maybe the port you try to use is not opened. 
Did you try it somewhere else? Give a friend the code and try it together with him. Make sure your routers allow to use the ports in case it still doesn't work.

Comment: thanks sebastian..hmm..so, does the port need to be opened in the client side as well for this to work? also, if i run the client from my friend's computer like you suggested do i need to make sure port forwarding is configured in both routers and firewall need to be disabled in both computers?

Comment: but when i run both client and server on the same computer in the university then it works..does that mean the port wasn't blocked?

Comment: Given that it works on the same computer, its a problem with the accessibility of the server computer. **1.** The port has to be reachable, meaning that, first, the `new ServerSocket()` and `server.accept()` must execute without throwing an exception. Any firewall on the **server** also has to allow an incoming connection to that port. **2.** The client must use an IP that is specific to that particular computer. If it uses a global external IP and the computer is on a subnet then unless **port forwarding** is configured, it won't connect.

Comment: If you intend to have this program work over the Internet, you can use [this](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) tool to check if the port is open and reachable on your **server** computer. Start your program and then use the website to see if its reachable.

Comment: thanks CPU Terminator, ok it shows closed on that port. Also, i found information in the university webpage saying "The Virtual Private Network (VPN) Client is required to access protected campus resources from either on or off campus. A client program on the user's machine creates an encrypted connection to the accessed area of the BYU network." Although, i dont know what a vpn is..does this have to do with the failure?

Comment: this is strange..i used that tool, ran server in my computer and then checked for the port which was set to 3001 it shows that port is closed. but why?

Comment: Your computer is probably behind a router thats blocking the inbound connection. If you are in a local subnet (where your IPv4 is something like 192.xxx.xxx.xxx) then you may need to configure your router to forward the connection to your computer (port forwarding).

The VPN stuff you posted doesn't seem to be directly related, but it does imply that you probably can't send data from outside the BYU network in (to your specific computer)

Comment: CPU Terminator, i have already configured the router to port forward 3000 to 3010 to my ipaddress...and i found my ip from ipconfig. the tool site gives you external ip address as well but i tried both and still is shows port closed.

Comment: i have also disabled windows firewall in my computer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41563/discussion-between-cpu-terminator-and-user734861)

Comment: ok thanks..i am in there.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when your client code try to connect to server and send "string massage" to server
at this time server read inputstream (by bufferreader) 
i.e. line = r.readLine(); // server code

here it would wait for \n or \r or \n\r (Line Feed, Carriage Return )at the end of String.

so you need to append last character as \n or \r or \n\r both side while sending massage to server or vis-versa..

```
.
.
.
    do
                {
                    line = r.readLine();
                    line = line +"\n"; // Add this line
                    if ( line != null )
                        System.out.println(line);
                    line = con.readLine();
                    w.println(line);
                }
.
.
.
```

@Client code